# How to execute multiple CLI commands in a python script?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, teamforge

I am using TeamForge's CLI to create artifacts in the Defects tracker section. The CLI file/executable is called "ctf" with no extensions. I want to use a python script to create artifacts but can only execute one command at most. I want to create a bug in one shot. This is the code I have so far:

```
import os
os.system("./ctf    go tracker1234;             # going to Defects section
                    create;                     # creating an artifact
                    set title This Is A Title;  # setting artifact's fields
                    set description desc123; 
                    set Product [Product 23]; 
                    set build_number Not known; 
                    set Severity Catastrophic; 
                    set steps_to_reproduce 1st comment; 
                    set Component [component 4]; 
                    set Version [version 19]; 
                    commit)                     # saving the artifact on TeamForge
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
sh: 1: create: not found
sh: 1: commit: not found
```

So I believe that these commands are not being executed sequentially or in the order that I have specified. This means that each command is being executed separately. Any suggestions to get these commands running in the order that I have specified?

Let me know if further explanation is required.

**Update**

I just found out that you can do this: `go tracker1234 create` which is two steps in one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a command in python subprocess popen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985888/formatting-a-command-in-python-subprocess-popen)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm not using awk, grep, etc.. This is an independent CLI. It does not follow the same format as awk and grep

Comment: That question is not awk-specific, the same rules apply to any command. To `shell=True`/`os.system`, you need to pass exactly what you would type at the shell prompt.

Comment: Wait a second... do you need to pass the commands **on the standard input** rather than on the command line?!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Yes, I am not using linux shell, I am passing to an independent CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to quote your arguments to ctf; just look at this:

```
>>> os.system("echo hi; echo again;")
hi
again
```

versus:

```
>>> os.system("echo 'hi; echo again;'")
hi; echo again;
```

The semicolon terminates a command in a shell. If your arguments contain semicolons, you must quote them so they don't break your list of arguments.

However, according to the [CTF guidelines](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.labs/wiki/CLIFAQ#section-CLIFAQ-InLinuxCanIUseAShBangInMyScripts), their way of handling such a situation with multiple commands seems to be putting them into a script and executing that with:

```
./ctf script.txt
```

Comment: The CLI's commands are not in the same format/syntax as bash, awk, grep, etc. These single quotes did not work. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: OK, I get it! So how about putting your commands [into a script](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.labs/wiki/CLIFAQ#section-CLIFAQ-InLinuxCanIUseAShBangInMyScripts) and execute that with `"./ctf script.txt"`?

Comment: Could you put the comment above in your answer. This has worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to you, too! Done; I hope my edits correctly express the solution you took?

Comment: Yes, I wrote all the commands I wanted to execute into script.txt and then used the command you provivded to execute the CLI

Comment: Hi, is it also possible to do the login onto a CLI server like that ?

Answer (score 1):

To pass information to your program **on the standard input,** either use

- your shell's facilities such as [here-document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) or [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), in the command line you specify, or
- Python's facilities, e.g. as per [How to launch and pass input to an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830372/how-to-launch-and-pass-input-to-an-external-program)

Alternatively, your program may have some "batch processing mode" that would allow you to provide your set of commands on the command line or in a file, but, looking at the [CTFCLI manual page](https://stage.ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.labs/wiki/CTFCLI#section-CTFCLI-CommandLineOptions), this doesn't seem likely.